# Excel: sum of first N numbers in range where N have upper limit but lower limit should be calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel sheet, let six data cells which contains numeric or blank (A1:A6). Column A7 is sum of first 5 large numbers.

Formula for A7 is =sumproduct(large(A1:A6,{1,2,3,4,5}))

This works fine if cell range A1:A6 contains at least 5 numbers, but if they are less than 5 then error. 
Data cells A1:A6 can not contain 0 instead of blank as 0 has meaning (attempted but scored 0) in compare to blank (not attempted).

How to fix upper limit based on count of non blank columns?

Comment: A1:A6 is **not** *six columns*.

Comment: ok, edited from six columns to six data cells.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
=sumifs(a1:a6, a1:a6, ">="&large(a1:a6, min(count(a1:a6), 5)))
```

What if the 5<sup>th</sup> largest is duplicated? Do you sum 6 numbers?

Comment: if 5th largest is duplicated then still sum of 5 numbers only.

Comment: Then you should use a 'helper' column with RANK and SUMIFS with that instead of LARGE.

Answer (score 0):

solving the problem caused by sumifs in case of same top values, i tried this SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(a1:a6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(5,COUNT(a1:a6))))))
and it solves problem.